# MiKTeX, and custom classes

Tags: installing, miktex, texmf, folders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex)

OK, so today is the very first time I've decided to try using TeX, and I have a few questions.

I've finally, after much fussing around, managed to get the basic tools up and running for me to make basic documents, but I'd like to make my own class definitions. Problem is, I don't want to (if possible) put my custom class files in the MikTeX folder structure. Is there a way I can configure it to reference a custom class folder where I store my stuff?

Comment: Regarding your question I’m sure this will help you: [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).